# How to dynamically change the "width" of a style in HTML template used in a NodeJs express app

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I am trying to dynamically set the value of width for a `<div>` that is being used as a **coloured bar** in an HTML template that I use to generate some PDFs. 
I am able to set other values using something like `{{my_value}}`, but using similar to that in the style doesn't seem to work.

I have tried using `width: {{my_value}}%`.
I have also tried setting the value by assigning the div to a class i.e. `.divClass { "width": {{my_value}} }`

HTML template :

```
<!-- Change the width dynamically to same value as {{my_value}} -->
<div style="width: 45% !important;">
<!-- Dynamic percentage below and above -->
<div style="padding-left:8px;">{{my_value}}%</div>
</div>
```

JS file contains the below

```
// Get the value from the POST
var val1 = req.body.val1;

//replace the value in the template
templateHtml = templateHtml.replace('{{my_value}}', val1);
```

If the POST `val1 = 20%` I would like to see that the coloured bar `<div>` is filled by only 20% and has the percentage written on it as well.
As it stands right now I am able to have the percentage written onto the bar but it simply fills the entire bar with a colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your server answer provide the percentage value : `percentage`. You can change the size from JS as bellow.

You can update size of an `<div>` within JS file with : 
`document.getElementById("myDiv").style.width = '50px';`

Here is a basic idea:

```js
document.getElementById("updateLoadBar").onclick = function() {
    updateLoadingBar()
};

function updateLoadingBar() {
    // Get input value
    // In your case your get this value from your template like this for example:
    // width = {{ percentage }};
    var width = document.getElementById("input-number").value;
    // Set darkBlue width
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = width + '%';

    // Avoiding that text overlap
    if (width >= 5) {
        // set text
        document.getElementById("text").textContent = width + "%";
    }
}
```

```css
.myButton {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
Select a number between 0 and 100:
<input id="input-number" type="number">
<input id="updateLoadBar" type="button" value="Update load bar" class="myButton">


<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find ready to use examples : [pure JS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/progress/) examples  if you use bootstrap in your project. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly it doesn't look like I can run any kind of JS script within the HTML to make those kinds of changes. The HTML is never actually run, simply used as: `var templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(HTML-FILE, 'utf8');`, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: If you build the HTML page, you can insert the Javascript and CSS block into. Copy past the js script between `<script> ... Your JS code ... </script>`. It's the same with the CSS style : <style> ... CSS code ... </style> . Not sure that answer ?

Comment: I myself am not building the HTML template, however your comment did help me think about this in a different way and brought me to a solution.
Creating the <div> within my JS and using the template.replace to bring it into the HTML, so thank you for that

Comment: Glad that helped you. Feel free to accept the answer :)